# maven checkstyle plugin's JavaDocMethod attributes are not found during build

Tags: maven, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I want to fail the maven build when any public method doesn't have valid javadoc. I'm using maven checkstyle plugin as suggested over this site. But, **it's giving me an error during build that the property allowUndeclaredRTE is not found.** On commenting this, it gives error on another property.

My code snippet from pom is below:

```
<build>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <logViolationsToConsole>true</logViolationsToConsole>
        <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
        <checkstyleRules>
            <module name="JavadocMethod">
                <property name="scope" value="public" />
                <property name="allowUndeclaredRTE" value="true" />
                <property name="allowMissingParamTags" value="false" />
            </module>
        </checkstyleRules>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after removing the tag checkstyleRules, it worked as expected. Below is complete working code snippet.

```
<build>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <logViolationsToConsole>true</logViolationsToConsole>
            <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</build>
```